# Hiding C++ symbols with -fvisibility=hidden

Tags: c++, c, gcc, clang, shared-libraries

I have a C++ library with a C API, and I have set the `-fvisibility=hidden` compiler flag,
and then I have set  `__attribute__ ((visibility ("default")))` on C API methods.

However, I still see visible C++ symbols. When I create a debian package for my library,
I get the following [symbols file](https://github.com/GrokImageCompression/grok/blob/debian/master/debian/libgrokj2k1.symbols)

Why are these symbols still visible ?

Comment: Are they imported symbols? You can't hide such symbols

Comment: Thanks, I have a static C++ 11 thread pool in the library, and these symbols seem to be referencing that thread pool.

Comment: You should run your symbols file through `c++filt` which converts the "mangled" symbol names to what is readable [in the `c++` sense]. If you do, you'll find that two thirds of the symbols are `std::whatever`, and not _your_ symbols. So, they are being pulled in because of the STL. You may not be able to control them. The other symbols are `grk_*`, if that helps.

Comment: ahhhh, ok. So, should I put the filtered symbols file as the lib*.symbols file ? This is the script: `sed 's/ \(_.*\) \(.*\)/ (c++)"\1" \2/' libgrokj2k.symbols | c++filt`

Comment: There are object file utilities (e.g. `readelf`, `objdump`, `objcopy`, etc) that may allow you to edit/patch your object files. Or, you might be able to use a linker script. Or, you could compile with `-S` to get a `.s` file. You could then write a [perl/python] script to modify the asm source and add/change whatever attribute(s) you need to change the visibility. Then, just do: `c++ -c modified.s`

Comment: @CraigEstey very interesting, thanks! I will have to take a look. If you convert your comments to an answer, I will mark it correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should run your symbols file through `c++filt` which converts the "mangled" symbol names to what is readable [in the `c++` sense].

If you do, you'll find that two thirds of the symbols are `std::whatever`, and not *your* symbols. So, they are being pulled in because of the STL. You may not be able to control them.

The other symbols are grk_*, if that helps.

There are object file utilities (e.g. `readelf`, `objdump`, `objcopy`, etc) that may allow you to edit/patch your object files.

Or, you might be able to use a linker script.

Or, you could compile with `-S` to get a `.s` file. You could then write a [perl/python] script to modify the asm source and add/change whatever attribute(s) you need to change the visibility. Then, just do: `c++ -c modified.s`

---

For a given symbol (e.g.):

```
int __attribute__((visibility("hidden")))
main(void)
{

    return 0;
}
```

---

The asm file is:

```
    .file   "main.c"
    .text
    .globl  main
    .hidden main
    .type   main, @function
main:
.LFB0:
    .cfi_startproc
    pushq   %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
    .cfi_offset 6, -16
    movq    %rsp, %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa_register 6
    movl    $0, %eax
    popq    %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa 7, 8
    ret
    .cfi_endproc
.LFE0:
    .size   main, .-main
    .ident  "GCC: (GNU) 8.3.1 20190223 (Red Hat 8.3.1-2)"
    .section    .note.GNU-stack,"",@progbits
```

Notice the asm directive:

```
.hidden main
```

Even without such a directive, it should be easy to write a script to add one [after the corresponding `.globl`]

Comment: thanks again. I am still a bit confused: why are only these particular STL symbols visible? There are plenty of other STL functions I am using, and they don't seem to appear on the list.